# Cron error: file could not be created

Tags: 6, cron

Cron seems to complete, but I get a message stating that a file could not be created.

Do you have any idea about what is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the 777 directory permission to your temp folder. Like....
sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/html/yoursite/sites/default/files/temp/

Please check images for more understanding. enter image description here

[image]

and command for give 777  permission to that directory like...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a file permissions issue. Check this: https://drupal.org/node/244924

Comment: Yes, I agree but I made no permission changes. My hosting company (GreenGeeks) is not helping.I'm trying to locate the directory now.

Comment: Some hosting companies does some maintenance on the servers that sometimes affects the file permissions. Check how is currently the file permissions at the admin panel of the web hosting service. 
Also, at admin/settings/file-system check for errors messages on the "file system paths" and "temp directory". If you have enabled the dblog or the syslog module, check the logs to get more info about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the temporary directory link found at sitename/admin/config/media/file-system to /tmp and save.